# Retrieving the stopped/started status of a program via API in Exact Target?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, php

We have a few Programs that we need to check to see if they are started/stopped. Is there a way to check these statuses via API?

My first attempt was using the `AsyncActivityStatus` object, but it seems this is only useful for Programs that have either already ran or are in the process of running.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AsynchApexJob object to query status. [You may find this article useful in your case.](http://www.tehnrd.com/batch-apex-status-bar/)

You can use SOQL like -

```
Select TotalJobItems, Status, NumberOfErrors, MethodName, JobType, 
JobItemsProcessed, Id, CreatedDate, CreatedById, CompletedDate, ApexClassId, 
ApexClass.Name From AsyncApexJob
```

You can find all available field in [AsyncApexJob](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_asyncapexjob.htm) in this [documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_asyncapexjob.htm).

Comment: I can't find any documentation on this. Can you provide a link to any?

Comment: I have updated my answer with URL. You can check this documentation for alll available fields for query.

Comment: I'm some code from ExactTarget, and this object doesn't seem available. Is this only available on the Salesforce side?

Comment: My Bad, I didnt knew that you are trying it in ExactTarget. My solution is for Salesforce.

Comment: I actually was unaware that there was a Marketing Cloud in both Exact Target and Salesforce until now. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: I have updated question title to avoid confusion.